# Why can't I make an SVG from an image map?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have an `img` tag as the sole child of a `<div id="container">` tag. `width`, `height`, and `usemap` are all set on the image, as are `style="position:absolute;"` and `usemap="#amap"`.

My quest: to write Javascript that adds an SVG overlay to the image showing the areas of the imagemap, preserving `title` tooltips. To that end, I have written the following code in a `script` element in the `head`:

```
function makeCircle(area)
{
  var c = document.createElement("circle");
  var coords = area.coords.split(",");

  c.setAttribute("cx", coords[0]);
  c.setAttribute("cy", coords[1]);
  c.setAttribute("r", coords[2]);

  c.className = "svg_shape";

  var t = document.createElement("title");
  t.innerHTML = area.title;
  c.appendChild(t);

  return c;
}

function makeRect(area)
{
  var r = document.createElement("rect");
  var coords = area.coords.split(",");

  r.setAttribute("x", coords[0]);
  r.setAttribute("y", coords[1]);

  r.setAttribute("width", coords[2] - coords[0]);
  r.setAttribute("height", coords[3] - coords[1]);

  r.className = "svg_shape";

  var t = document.createElement("title");
  t.innerHTML = area.title;
  r.appendChild(t);

  return r;
}

function makePoly(area)
{
  var p = document.createElement("polygon");
  var coords = area.coords.split(",");

  var coords2 = [];
  coords2.push(coords[0]);
  for(var i = 1; i < coords.length; i++)
  {
    if(i % 2 === 0)
      coords2.push(" ");
    else
      coords2.push(",");

    coords2.push(coords[i]);
  }

  p.setAttribute("points", coords2.join(""));

  p.className = "svg_shape";

  var t = document.createElement("title");
  t.innerHTML = area.title;
  p.appendChild(t);

  return p;
}

function makeSVG()
{
  var container = document.getElementById("container");
  var image = container.firstElementChild;
  var map = document.getElementsByName("amap")[0];
  var svg = document.createElement("svg");

  container.appendChild(svg);

  svg.setAttribute("width", image.width);
  svg.setAttribute("height", image.height);
  svg.style.position="absolute";
  //svg.style.width=image.width;
  //svg.style.height=image.height;

  var children = map.children;
  for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++)
  {
    var area = children[i];
    var type = area.shape;
    if(type==="circle")
    {
      svg.appendChild(makeCircle(area));
    }
    else if(type==="rect")
    {
      svg.appendChild(makeRect(area));
    }
    else if(type==="poly")
    {
      svg.appendChild(makePoly(area));
    }
  }
}

window.onload = makeSVG;
```

`svg_shape` is a CSS class that basically just makes the shape visible.

Here's the thing: Even though Chrome's DevTools shows that the svg element is being generated with all the appropriate children (copying the body HTML it generates into a new static page produces the right results), it doesn't appear on the page. Further inspection shows that the SVG has dimensions 0×0, even though it has nonzero `width` and `height` attributes. What gives?

Comment: You need to create SVG elements in the proper namespace, using `document.createElementNS`.

Comment: That worked! The only problem is that setting `className` doesn't work, but `setAttribute` works there, as does changing the stylesheet to affect the shape elements instead of making a new `svg_shape` class. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use createElementNS to create SVG elements.

For [classNames](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#__svg__SVGStylable__className) it's

```
r.className.baseVal = "svg_shape"
```

to allow for SMIL in SVG, animated and base (non-animated) values are separate.